# Can I export/import a Windows Profile

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, user-profiles

I am about to move some users off a domain to using stand-alone account, and I'd like to keep all the users settings (eg thunderbird cache/saved passwords etc).

Is it possible to export the settings from one profile and import them into a fresh one? Or alternatively, alter the Domain profile to become a Local profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompted by @LowvaPrg's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/372375/84636) I found a commercial tool which did exactly what I was looking for with an absolute minimum of fuss.

The tool is "User Profile Wizard 3.5" by ForensiT and can be found on their website [here](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html). There is a free version not intended for commercial use but I went for the Professional version - not for the extra features, but for business use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with one caveat: Passwords will not be saved since they are encrypted.

1. You would log in as the new local user, thereby creating a new profile.
2. Then you want to reboot and log in as administrator. You reboot to release all files from memory, so they will not be in use when copied.
3. Then you go to My computer>Properties>Advanced>User Profiles, and highlight the old domain user profile (usually the largest one), and click "Copy to". "Browse" to the C:\Documents and Settings\local user profile and click "Change" under "Permitted to use" and select the local user. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. Is it the same procedure for XP and W7?

Comment: Ahh Windows 7. There are two differences: One is the location has changed from \Documents and Settings to \Users. Second, when trying to copy the profile, the button is grayed out and has been disabled. I found the Windows enabler to get around that: http://www.bluemoonpcrepair.com/wp/?p=39 If this works for you, please come back and upvote and mark as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the long silence - I've now tried this but weirdly I don't get that greyed out button either in XP or W7. Perhaps this only works *after* leaving the domain, do you think?

Comment: I'm am worried about leaving the domain in case I can't rejoin (with profiles intact) if it goes wrong...

Comment: You can safely leave and join a domain with no loss of profile data assuming you do not delete the folders.

Comment: @shufler thanks that is very helpful. Forgive the over-caution but do you have any references to back that statement up?

Comment: Removing a computer from a domain does not delete the profiles stored in the file system. As the profiles store the user's SID when you rejoin the domain they will receive their profile as expected. I not aware of any documentation that states it this way.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is using the **windows 7 User Profile Transfer Wizard**, sense it copies all the settings and it has a nice user interface, just be patient is a bit slow.

Comment: Is that the same as "Windows Easy Transfer"? If so I was able to export a profile but not to choose the local profile when it came to reimport. Or do you mean [this](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html) commercial tool (I am happy to use a paid-for solution if it works)?

Comment: yes, is the same

Comment: Which do you mean? Because if you mean the commercial tool I will accept your answer - it is ace.